# Fastlane – company usability?

Tags: android, ios, deployment, automation, fastlane

We are currently discussing in the company, if the tool Fastlane and its subtools (screenshots, Beta deployment, AppStore Deployment...) are suitable for business? Is there any documented proof, that the tools is running just "local" on the server or computer and not sending any stuff like credentials etc.? It would be really nice, if someone of you would provide some documents or something like that to proof it's usability for business. This tools would really make our working process much better!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastlane is 100% open source so seeing what all fastlane does is completely documented - https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

fastlane runs 100% local but does communicate to the external services that you want to use (ie: iOS Developer Portal, iTunesConnect, TestFlight, HockyeApp, Crashlytics, etc) which do require credentials being sent to login. fastlane and its tools are used by a lot of different businesses so I would say they are suitable for business but if they are suitable for your business is not something that I am able to answer.